# Probability that N cells of a $K\times K$ table hold the value 1

Tags: probability, combinatorics

Given a $K\times K$ table, each cell can hold the value of either 1 or 0, and the values are determined randomly. I need to calculate:

1. The probability that exactly N cells hold the value of 1
2. Same as (1) but this time each cell can hold one of the values 0-9

for (2) I have $\binom{K^2}{N}$ ways to choose cells to hold the value 1, and assuming that all the digits have the same probability I got $$P_2=\binom{K^2}{N}(0.1)^{N}(0.9)^{K^2-N}$$
but I am not sure if I can do the same for (1) because by choosing the N cells that will hold the value 1, which is $\binom{K^2}{N}(0.5)^N$, it is already decided which cells will have 0 thus I thought $$P_1 = \binom{K^2}{N}(0.5)^N$$ but on the other hand (1) is a private case of (2) so the same calculation should apply while adjusting the probability of each value and at this point I'm not sure which way is correct

Comment: Even once you have chosen the N cells to have the value 1, you still need all of those cells to get 1 and all the other cells to get 0.  There is a 1/2 probability for all of those choices so you should still get a factor of $(0.5)^{K^2}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In how many ways you can choose the $N$ cells out of $K^2$ which contains ones ? As you said there are $K^2 \choose N$ ways to do so. Besides, there are $2^{K^2}$ possible sequences of $\{0,1\}$ , therefore the solution is $\displaystyle\frac{K^2 \choose N}{2^{K^2}} = {K^2 \choose N} (0.5)^{K^2}$.

Your doubt is simple to explain, you are not choosing the positions of the ones and of the zeroes with the $\frac12$'s probability for each cell but the number on the cell, if you have $N$ cells with ones this doesn't affect at all (because of independence) the numbers on the other $K^2-N$ cells.